# GeoServer GetFeatureInfo with time range

Tags: geoserver, wms, getfeatureinfo, time-series

I've been building a WMS service for time series data following this tutorial:

http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html

Everything is fine and my GetMap function work well and all the maps are loaded according to their data. The problem is when I want to use the GetFeatureInfo function. If I use it to retrieve the feature value of a point for a single date it works well, but if I try to add the time range parameter I only get the feature info of the starting date.

I use it in this way: http://localhost/geoserver/cite/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&QUERY_LAYERS=cite%3A9_S_int&STYLES=ocean&LAYERS=cite%3A9_S_int&INFO_FORMAT=application%2Fjson&FEATURE_COUNT=50&I=50&J=50&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=101&HEIGHT=101&BBOX=-77.27783203125%2C-46.5380859375%2C-72.83935546875%2C-42.099609375&TIME=2018-08-09/2018-08-11&

I've always used the time range in this way for all WMS service I used. Now that I'm trying to build my own WMS service I get this problem.  I've enabled the time dimension setting the presentation value to List.

Here in the following the layer properties retrieved with GetCapabilities:

```
            <Layer queryable="1" opaque="0">
                <Name>9_S_int</Name>
                <Title>CMEMS_int_S</Title>
                <Abstract/>
                <KeywordList>
                    <Keyword>CMEMS_int_S</Keyword>
                    <Keyword>WCS</Keyword>
                    <Keyword>ImageMosaic</Keyword>
                </KeywordList>
                <CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS>
                <CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
                <EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
                    <westBoundLongitude>-83.8750025510788</westBoundLongitude>
                    <eastBoundLongitude>-63.79166538715362</eastBoundLongitude>
                    <southBoundLatitude>-55.70833460489909</southBoundLatitude>
                    <northBoundLatitude>-35.62500127156576</northBoundLatitude>
                </EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
                <BoundingBox CRS="CRS:84" minx="-83.8750025510788" miny="-55.70833460489909" maxx="-63.79166538715362" maxy="-35.62500127156576"/>
                <BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:4326" minx="-55.70833460489909" miny="-83.8750025510788" maxx="-35.62500127156576" maxy="-63.79166538715362"/>
                <Dimension name="time" default="current" units="ISO8601">2018-08-08T00:00:00.000Z,2018-08-09T00:00:00.000Z,2018-08-10T00:00:00.000Z,2018-08-11T00:00:00.000Z,2018-08-14T00:00:00.000Z</Dimension>
                <Style>
                    <Name>raster</Name>
                    <Title>Default Raster</Title>
                    <Abstract>A sample style that draws a raster, good for displaying imagery</Abstract>
                </Style>
            </Layer>
```

Are there other properties I should check to enable the time range capability?

Comment: `Everything is fine and my GetMap function work well and all the maps are loaded according to their data. `  What is meant by that statement?  I mean you do a GetMap request with a time range and you get a single image which represents the time range data?  A GetFeatureInfo request is a point location in that result, so I would assume it can only be for one time.

Comment: Thanks to StackOverflow's reputation system I cannot comment, only post an answer. This question is 2 years old, but do you mind sharing if you solved this problem, and how?

Answer (score 1):

ncWMS is an extension that will allow you do do what you are asking for.

You need to incall ncWMS https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/ncwms/index.html  It is only available as a nightly build extension (ie its not officially supported) from https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver/2.18.x/community-latest/

The differences fom GetFeatureInfo are

1. REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo -> REQUEST=GetTimeSeries
2. QUERY_LAYERS={layer-group}&STYLES&LAYERS={layer-group} -> QUERY_LAYERS={imagemosaic-name}&STYLES&LAYERS={imagemosaic-name}
3. TIME=2021-05-26T18:00:00.000Z/2021-05-27T20:00:00.000Z